# Two classes with some common attributes without heritage

Tags: java

I have two classes with some common attributes :

```
public class A { 
private String a;
private String b;
private String c;
// setters & getters
}
public class B {
private String a;
private String b;
private String c;
// setters & getters
}
```

Without hiretage , i want to create a generic method that can accept one of this two classes

```
public <T> void myMethod(T object){
object.getC(); // "c" attribute of class A and B
}
```

How can i do this in java 8

Comment: You should be using an interface and define getC() method in there. Then you can pass the interface to the method.

Comment: Why don't you want inheritance?

Comment: If they are not of the same type or they don't suppose to have the same super type, it doesn't make sense to do such a thing

Comment: Thanks for reply @Brenin, please can u give me an example using code , i'm debutante , thank u so much ^^

Comment: Interfaces or inheritance would probably the best way to go but in case you _really_ need them to be completely separate you can try to provide function parameters (i.e. `Function<T,V>`) that are able to extract the properties from the classes. Then you'd use it like `myMethod(instanceOfA, A::getC)` or `myMethod(instanceOfB, B::getC)`. But I'll reiterate: if you can use a common interface then use that!

Comment: @mzlle then look up java - interface. don't ask for custom made code, you won't actually learn anything by just copy pasting. learning to work with them will make it far easier to understand it and be able to do it yourself next time, compared to just copy-pasting someone else's code

Answer (score 2):

You can define an interface such as this:

```
interface ISomeInterfaceToGetC {
    String getC();
}
```

Implementation is simple:

```
class A implements ISomeInterfaceToGetC {
    @Override
    public String getC(){
        return c;
    }
}
```

Then both your classes can implement this interface and instead of passing `T object` you can pass `ISomeInterfaceToGetC implementationObject` and call `implementationObject.getC();` which will return your String.

Comment: good , thank u Brenin

Answer (score 2):

Why not just go for separate POJO class instead, which will serve both that common code and no need to inherit or implement.

```
class Data{
    private String a;
    public String getA(){
        return this.a;
    }
    /* TO DO */
}

class A {
   private Data data;
    /* TO DO */
}

class B {
   private Data data;
    /* TO DO */
}

public void myMethod(Data data){
    data.getA();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic way to do this then you can follow these steps.

**a**. First define an interface

```
    public interface Sea {

       public int getC();
    }
```

**b**. Then class let your two classes implement the interface.

```
public class Eh implements Sea {

    private int c = -1;

    @Override
    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
}

public class Bee implements Sea {

    private int c = -1;

    @Override
    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

**c**. Now you can use a generic method with a parameter that takes any generic object which implements from the interface `Sea`.

```
public class GenericClass<T extends Sea> {
    public void getGenericSea(T object) {
        object.getC();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest you to use and interface here. However, if you really want to follow your original way. Following is an example.

```
public <T> void myMethod(T object){
    String val;//Common type for both Class A and B

    if (object instanceof A)
        val = ((A) object).getC();
    else if (object instanceof B)
        val = ((B) object).getC();
    else
        val = null; //Unsupported type

    System.out.println(val);
}
```